# Selenium.WebDriver! How get submenu of dropdown menu using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I can't get the submenu item of my dropdown menu because the submenu is visible only on mouseOver event of main menu item.

**My Code:**

*mouseOver event on main menu item*

```
     IWebElement element = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id(elementID));

     Actions action = new Actions(WebDriver);
     action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
```

When I try to get the submenu item of my menu I get the following error: " ... ***OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element***".

What you advise me to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a Google search and found an article **SELENIUM WEBDRIVER – HOW TO CLICK ON A HIDDEN LINK OR MENU** with a work-around of my issue. 
[Here's the article.](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)

Using the **.mouseover()** method:

```
 js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('Fruits')\").mouseover();"); // Mouse hove to main menu  
 webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Banana")).Click();
```

OR using the **.hover()** method:

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('div#Fruits').hover();");  
  webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Banana")).Click();
```

OR using the **.mouseenter()** method:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('div#Fruits').mouseenter();")  
webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Banana")).Click();
```